# return string variable from Main()

Tags: c#

I would like to return a string variable from my Main() method. I've returned int variables. But I'm not sure if it's possible to return a string variable from Main() when you exit the program?

Any ideas?

Here is my int code:

```
    public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static int Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        int error = 1;

        return error;

    }

}
```

If I change int to string, I get this error: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. So obviously this is not allowed. What is the correct approach?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: if you have written code to return an integer from Main() then surely the code for returning an string will also be same. I wonder where you get stuck.

Comment: would it? I tried, but it gave me error when compiling. Please have a look at the edited post...

Comment: How and from where would you use the returned value?

Comment: @kalyan: No, you're missing the point - a `Main` method with an `int` return value is a valid assembly entry point. A `Main` method with a `string` return value is not.

Comment: @Andreas Brinck: I would use it in another application (from 3rd party). This application has the function to retrieve the return value upon exit of another launched exe inside their environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you cannot return a string. What you can do on the other hand is write the string to the standard output and then from the program that's calling this program capture that output.

Answer (score 3):

Some decent ideas here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a99a8b0d-fb49-4caf-8107-fc04bd48d3f9/

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't return string from Main method. The entry point can optionally only return an int value. As, this return value is used in application termination (§10.2). or use void Main if you dont want to return.